# Update query to find out registered ids from an array in php

Tags: php

I am trying to find out which ids in an array are already registered or updated in the database. hOW can i customize my query to add array of ids `$ids` and make query to check for all the ids in the array if

```
1- They are Registered And their visibility is 1 and their update_time > :update_time
```

Here is the code

```
function GetOnlineContacts() 
{
    try {
        $conn = $this->GetDBConnection();
        $update_time = time() - 120;

        $ids = array($_POST['ids']);

        $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT linkedInId FROM users WHERE update_time > :update_time AND visibility = 1');
        $statement->bindParam(':update_time', $update_time, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();

        $conn = null;




        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        throw $e;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why the java tag ?

Comment: ah ya sorry. I am working in java. absent mind -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your id field was named `id`, then try this

```
$ids = implode(",",$_POST['ids']);
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT linkedInId FROM users WHERE update_time > :update_time AND visibility = 1 AND id IN(:ids)');
$statement->bindParam(':update_time', $update_time, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(':ids', $ids, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Note, for this to work you will have to have those `ids` coming from your html form with name `ids[]`

Comment: id i have replaced with linkedInId because that's what i want to search

Comment: whats the output of `print_r($ids);` after the `implode` line?

Comment: when i do return $ids they return xxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxx all the ids i sent

Comment: $row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $row is null